# In Azure ADO, the iteration taskboard has a diff order than the iteration backlog

Tags: azure, user-stories, backlog

Thanks in advance.

In Azure I go to Boards and then Sprints.
When I switch between the Taskboard and Backlog tabs I expect the order of the user stories to be the same on both tabs but they are not.  This started about 2 months ago and is happening for me only.

I cannot find any settings anywhere, that affects order.  I want the order of user stories to remain the same when I switch between tabs.

If someone knows how to fix this please let me know.

Thanks.